# Do materials on an object stay when 3d printing?

Tags: materials, color, 3d-printing

I am doing some research for Blender 3D Printing but i haven't seen this question asked so I will be asking it. I am making a few meshes in blender and i need them to be a certain color. I want to know if the colors i assigned that object in the Blender software will be printed. If it doesn't work that way, is there a way to make it that way? Sorry i am a beginner at 3d printing/Blender and thank you in advance!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541#57541

Comment: **That's not so much a Blender question and much more of a printer question, so I'll answer it in the comments.** Yes, there are already printers out there which are capable of printing colored objects. If they are able to get the material colors from Blender models, is a whole other question. And for the sake of completeness, no, your average run-off-the-mill 3D printer for a couple of hundred Dollars is certainly not able to print in colors. At the current state, you might be better off asking those questions at a 3D printing service that offers color printing.

Comment: ok thank you for the information!